# I am using match_parent but half of the elements are out of the screen!(LinearLayout)

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I opened an old project to work on a college project. The app was working fine, but when I install the app again all of my screen have the same problem which is the elements are going out of the screen! I will show one of my screens with its code.

- [This is the layout form Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MX2d.png)
- [This is the layout form Android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgN9C.png)
- [This is my app on landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWUF1.png)
  **I have just discovered this.**

---

I have the same problem in my phone. I don't wanted it in landscape mode(If that whats happing).

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp"
        tools:context=".CustomActivity">
    
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/purple_700"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#fff" />
    
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/digits" />
    
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sDigits"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/sign" />
    
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sSign"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
    
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/times" />
    
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sTimes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/seconds" />
    
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/sSeconds"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCreate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:text="@string/string_create"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Android Manifest File (`AndroidManifest.xml`), add this attribute
`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`
to your `<activity>`.

Something like this:

```
<activity android:name=".your_activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        <!--other activity attributes->
</activity>
```

Comment: Now that didn't work. :(
But I know for sure now its nothing to deal with landscape/portrait now.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was using fragment container View in my main xml activity. And somehow the Width is 777dp and the Hight is 1276dp! I changed it to match parent

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
android:id="@+id/fragment2"
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
android:layout_width="777dp"
android:layout_height="1276dp"
app:defaultNavHost="true"
app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```